# PHP str_replace Error

Tags: php, str-replace

Can any one tell me why this code doesn't work?

`$bodytag = str_replace("id=\"", "id=1\"",`
`"$p = $_GET['p'];`
`echo '<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"styles.php?id=$p\">';`
`");`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you see PHP's documentation about `str_replace()`? Don't `echo` inside a function and don't use ";" either like you use now.

Comment: You better see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: yes, a php parser can tell you why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are meaning to do?

```
$p = (int)$_GET['p'];
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.php?id='.$p.'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$bodytag = str_replace('id="', 'id='.$_GET['p'].'"','style.php?id="');
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$bodytag.'">';
```

Dont know why you escape the " in the echo, cause you use ' to print the link-tag.
if you want /" to be in you url instead of ", just add it to the code

/edit: sry, didn't think about what i wrote. Just saw the mistake without looking through my stuff. But Ing's solutions is way better. Just remember the syntax to use str_replace.

Comment: Sorry, this will not work. `str_replace` arguments in your case are wrong, a good example is `str_replace($from, $to, $string)`. Will remove my -1 when fixed.